# Error while Test Map in Biztalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I have made some changes to the existing map and tried to test the map.
The Changes I made is adding a scripting fuctoid with the following code

```
public string Code(string recode, string amount)
{
double k = Convert.ToDouble(amount);
if(k>0)
{
return " ";
}
else return recode;
}
```

also added the logical functoid and value mapping in another field like
[image]

When I clicked the Test Map option, I am getting an error message like this

[image]

I am not sure what is going wrong. Can anybody help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: need to see the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no error in the code or functoids. The assembly file version was set a 1.1.* . When I changed it and did test map option,it worked.